{{Event.EventDefinitionKeyPrefix.First Name}} not working
how to retrieve dynamic value of data extension column such as "First Name"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried
{{Event.EventDefinitionKeyPrefix."First Name"}}
?

answering own question:
needed to use escape characters, incase there's space inside coumn name. {{Event.${eventDefinitionKeyPrefix}.\"First Name\"}};

Some time ago, it was possible to search for this Entry Source Data Extension's attributes in the dev tools but with some latest updates of SFMC, it is no longer available.
The most convenient approach would be to add any "Sales & Service Cloud" Activity to the Journey's canvas (e.g. Opportunity), and in the tab where you need to map fields, select the field from your Entry Source Data Extension -


hi Niko, thank for your response, how will you manage if the column "ContactId" got whitespace in between, for e.g: "Contact ID"
now when i do {{Event.DE_KEY_PREFIX_ID.Contact ID}}, journey builder is not able to extract contact id value
